# MongoDB query to 'return empty result set'

Tags: mongodb

I'm dynamically constructing and modifying a query in code.

I want a certain codepath to have the Collection return 0 documents.

I simply do `Collection.find({_id:null})` . This seems to work.

Just wondering if there was a more standard way to do this in MongoDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

null is a valid value for _id, so while that query may be fine for your data, in general it's not guaranteed to produce the empty result set:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.foo.insert({_id:null})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise > db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : null }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.foo.find({_id:null})
{ "_id" : null }
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

_id however does need to be *present* in each document, therefore a query insisting it isn't present should always return the empty result set:

```
db.foo.find({_id:{$exists:false}})
```

This only works for queries on top-level documents, naturally.

Comment: `null` is fine for my data because there's validation on `_id`. But your solution is airtight. thanks